# DllNotFoundException when importing "winmm.dll" in WP8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, pinvoke

I'm trying to import winmm.dll on a WP8.1 app to try and control device volume. Based on research from Google, I have created a Windows Runtime Component to wrap the actual function call, and then I call this from the main app. Since the issue is clearly in the wrapper, here's the code:

```
public sealed class VolumeControl
{
    [DllImport("winmm.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern int waveOutSetVolume(IntPtr uDeviceID, int dwVolume);

    public static void Set(int volume)
    {
        // get volume as proportion of maximum
        double newVolume = ushort.MaxValue * volume / 10.0;

        // convert this into volume for two channels
        uint v = ((uint)newVolume) & 0xffff;
        uint vAll = v | (v << 16);

        // set volume
        waveOutSetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, (int)vAll);
    }
```

I have also enabled unsafe code in the wrapper's project properties. DllImport is possible for native libraries in WP8.1, as far as I understand. I don't expect this app to pass certification on the Windows Store, but still I can't see why this code wouldn't work on a developer unlocked device.

Any idea if I've missed something here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out that WP8.1 has a WinMMBase.dll rather than plain old winmm.dll.

I found this by running a web server hack to browse the System32 folder (see xda-developers). After downloading the dll and inspecting it with DLL Export (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html), I found that it does have the waveSetOutVolume function. The function itself doesn't seem to affect the volume though, but that wasn't the point of the question I guess :)

Comment: In what way does this address the question that you asked? Do you think the documentation in MSDN is wrong? How does the existence of an unpublished function that has the same name address the question that you asked. If you don't want to hear answers, why ask at all?

Comment: I guess my question itself was not clear. What I meant was that I was not able to access the function in winmm.dll (and I made it clear that this was not officially exposed in Windows Phone anyway). So I answered when I found out that the function was moved to WinMMBase.dll, because that answers my original question - and the function is accessible though it doesn't seem to actually alter the volume.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question that you asked, which is written above

Answer (score 1):

On Windows Mobile, all waveform audio function are implemented in 'coredll.dll'. Use this DLL instead of 'winmm.dll'.

Comment: Ah but switching out "coredll.dll" for "winmm.dll" still gives exactly the same DllNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743874.aspx) has the answer:

> **Requirements**
>
> Minimum supported client
>   Windows 2000 Professional [desktop apps only]

In other words this function is not available from Windows Store app.

Comment: No, apparently some people have been able to get it working on WP8 since the native DLLs do exist even though they aren't officially exposed [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=50288496). Hence this code _should_ work even though Microsoft wouldn't allow it for publication on the Windows Store.
Regardless, thanks for the reply :)